# Delete a specific outlook task from asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I have created a task programmatically (I have used NetOffice.OutlookApi) from my MVC application to outlook, and now I need to delete/update the task. I am not able to delete it through this code. It throws an error at `currExpl = outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();`. Can someone help me in this? I have searched a lot for a demo on this but couldn't find one!

```
    Outlook.Explorer currExpl = null;
    Outlook.Selection selection = null;
    object selectedItem = null;
    Outlook.TaskItem task = null;

    try
    {
       Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
       currExpl = outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
       // selection = currExpl.selectedItem;

       if (selectedItem is Outlook.TaskItem)
       {
          task = selectedItem as Outlook.TaskItem;
          if (task.IsRecurring)
          task.ClearRecurrencePattern();
           task.Delete();
       }
   }
```

The following exception is thrown:

> This is the debugger error : Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetOffice.OutlookApi._Explorer' to 'NetOffice.OutlookApi.Explorer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  Writer.Services E:\GMMS\GMMS\Writer.Services\StoredPr‌​ocedureService.cs    26‌​7   Active

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Basically I've followed this thread for task creation https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/06/12/outlook-tasks-create-get-delete/ however for deleting task the .ActiveExplorer() isn't working

Comment: What is the error message when you run the code on the line that you pointed out, is there an exception thrown?

Comment: Fantastic, but what is the exception? I assume you have a `catch(Exception ex)` in your `try` statement?

Comment: This is the debugger error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetOffice.OutlookApi._Explorer' to 'NetOffice.OutlookApi.Explorer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) Writer.Services E:\GMMS\GMMS\Writer.Services\StoredProcedureService.cs 267 Active

Comment: I do have a catch block, but as of now, I am facing a conflict between casting.